# Iterate over dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

I have multiple training and testing dataframes.

Example: train1,train2,train3 till train10. Same for test.

I would like to iterate over these dataframes, something like: (PS: Code is wrong but to give you idea): I don't want to concatenate them into one.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    y%i = train%i['Labels']
    X%i = train%i.drop('Labels',axis=1)
    clf.fit(X%i,y%i)
    output%i = clf.predict(test%i)
```

Can it be done?

Comment: what you need return ? only output ? or all x , y and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ... also , I do not think you need restore the middle variable like X,Y

```
variables = locals()
for i in list(range(1,11)):
    variables["y{0}".format(i)]= variables["train{0}".format(i)]['Labels']
    variables["x{0}".format(i)]= variables["train{0}".format(i)].drop('Labels',1)
    clf.fit(variables["x{0}".format(i)], variables["y{0}".format(i)])
    variables["output{0}".format(i)]= clf.predict(variables["x{0}".format(i)], variables["y{0}".format(i)])
```

---

What I will do

```
variables = locals()
for i in list(range(1,11)):
    y= variables["train{0}".format(i)]['Labels']
    x= variables["train{0}".format(i)].drop('Labels',1)
    clf.fit(x,y)
    variables["output{0}".format(i)]= clf.predict(x,y)
```

Comment: I'ts what I'm alooking for, I've a mistake, I did edit, at the end it's clf.predict(test%i), do I replace it with clf.predict(variables[test{0}.format(i)]) ?

Comment: @hdatas yes~:)~